# Why is this .NET IL null check not working as expected?

Tags: .net, cil

I'm writing some custom IL and need something equivalent to `return SomeStaticField != null;`. This was my natural conclusion:

```
volatile.ldsfld ...SomeStaticField //volatile is needed here for unrelated reasons
ldnull
ceq
not
ret
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I confirmed that SomeStaticField is null, but yet this function will end up returning true. I know C# uses branches for such a construct, and I could use it too, but it baffles me as to why this wouldn't have the expected behavior

A complete and verifiable example (as a library):

```
.assembly extern /*23000001*/ mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly 'BareMetal'
{
  .custom instance void class [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute::'.ctor'() =  (
                01 00 01 00 54 02 16 57 72 61 70 4E 6F 6E 45 78   // ....T..WrapNonEx
                63 65 70 74 69 6F 6E 54 68 72 6F 77 73 01       ) // ceptionThrows.

  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver  1:0:0:0
}
.module BareMetal.dll 


.namespace Earlz.BareMetal
{
  .class public auto ansi abstract sealed beforefieldinit BareMetal
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
  {
    .method public static hidebysig
           default bool FooTest ()  cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 2
        ldnull
        ldnull
        ceq
        not
        ret
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: It should work, [ceq is definitely used for null checks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023705/when-i-use-is-operator-why-there-is-only-a-null-check-in-il-code). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `not` is not it.  Always best to let the C# compiler generate the msil first and look at it with ildasm.exe.  Just about nobody thinks to use `cgt.un`.

Comment: @Heinzi I updated to add a complete example (replacing the ldsfld with a ldnull for simplicity)

Comment: @HansPassant is cgt safe to use against null and reference types? I assumed that was only valid for numerics

Comment: You want to file a bug report against the C# compiler?  Hehe.  It is safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`not` computes the bitwise complement of its operand: `~1` is `-2`, which, being non-zero, is true. The canonical way of negating a boolean is `ldc.i4.0 ; ceq`.

And, as @HansPassant pointed out, the canonical way of doing a `!= null` comparison directly is `cgt.un` -- all valid references are "greater than zero" when interpreted as unsigned values. That such comparisons are safe is explicitly documented in [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), section I.12.1.5:

> In particular, object references can be:
>
> ...
>
> 5. Created as a null reference (`ldnull`)
>
> ...
>
> Managed pointers have several additional base operations.
>
> ...
>
> 3. Unsigned comparison and conditional branches based on two managed pointers (`bge.un`, `bge.un.s`, `bgt.un`, `bgt.un.s`, `ble.un`,
>      `ble.un.s`, `blt.un`, `blt.un.s`, `cgt.un`, `clt.un`).

Comment: I've always used `brtrue` or `brfalse` for doing a null check since I don't have to do a `ldnull` for the comparison.  Is there a difference in this case that makes the comparison versions preferable?

Comment: @Kyle: no. This is just how you'd do it if you need the result of the comparison as a boolean, for whatever reason (maybe to combine expressions and save on branches later). If you want to branch immediately, `brtrue` and `brfalse` are indeed the common way to do it (so common that `brinst` and `brnull` are aliases, in fact). Of course you could also branch and load a constant boolean; what's better depends on what you're doing and what the JIT compiler ultimately generates.